# How to Use DropNet Client with UserId's received via Webhook

Tags: c#, dropbox-api, delta, dropnet

I am using DropBox Webhook to get the notification regarding any changes on DropBox.
I'll get user id from webhook.
I read there tutorial and they said that after getting user id's i have to call dropbox api on the behalf of that particular userid.

I also use DropNet nuget package for DropBox Communication. Now my question is how can i use the user id (that i'll retrieve via Webhook) to get all the changes. 
I know that i have to use "GetDelta" Routine but i don't know how can i create DropNet UserLogin on the basis of only "User Id" not on the basis of "User Access Token" and "User Secret Key", so that i can use "GetDelta" Routine.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *should* be using a user access token and user secret key. On the server, you'll need to keep a mapping of user IDs to access tokens. When you see a change for a given user, you'll look up that user's access token and make calls via DropNet using that.

Comment: Hi Smarx,
Actually that logic is doesn't fit in my scenario. Say i have a folder in Dropbox that have Some subfolders and i share subfolders link to 9-10 user's and my app is linked with my user credentials which means my app will have access to root folder and all subfolders. Now any of the user will make any change in dropbox and i'll get userid of that user from webhook but my app does'nt recognized that user (say user-A) because user-A is not linked with my app, i doesn't have user access key and secret of user-A, so how can i get changes that user-A has done. ???

Comment: This can't happen. You can't get a webhook referencing a user ID who hasn't actually linked your app. In the scenario you described, you should get a change for your user ID.